# (ffmpeg) avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264") fails

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

`avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264")` return `NULL`.

FFmpeg was configured with flags `--enable-gpl` and `--enable-libx264`

`ffmpeg -codecs | grep 264` returns `DEV.LS h264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vda ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )`

I need to create `libx264` encoder,. Where is my fault? How to init `AVCodec` with `libx264` codec.

```
AVCodec *encoder = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264");
if (!encoder) {
  av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you compiled x264 before ffmpeg and you had no compilation errors for the latter, is that right?

Comment: Did you call function "av_register_all()" before avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264")? If not, the first thing you need to do is to register all formats & codecs by calling "av_register_all()"

Comment: Yes, after several recompiles of ffmpeg, its working. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to call `av_register_all()` since FFMPEG 4.

Comment: try to list all enable codec with av_codec_iterate() function